# system:time_index missing Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I wrote the following code where an ImageCollection is multiplied by different scale factors (469 in total). I created a list with all the factors and I combined it with the imageCollection in order to multiply each month with its corresponding factor. The results show a final collection with the scale factor applied.

https://code.earthengine.google.com/203deb3d2f9c19afe9236f4e53efbd0c

However, the final ImageCollection misses the system:time_index property. I was trying to use .CopyProperties but honestly, I do not know where.

Any suggestion?

```
var sum_month = ee.List.sequence(0, 39*12).map(function(n) { // .sequence: number of years from starting year to present
  var start = ee.Date('1981-01-01').advance(n, 'month'); // Starting date
  var end = start.advance(1, 'month'); // Step by each iteration

  return ee.ImageCollection("UCSB-CHG/CHIRPS/DAILY")
        .filterDate(start, end)
        .sum()
        .set('system:time_start', start.millis());
});

var collection = ee.ImageCollection(sum_month)

var list = ee.List([
  0.884748080310752,
0.884748080310752,
0.884748080310752,
0.884748080310752,
0.884748080310752,
0.884748080310752,
0.884748080310752,
0.884748080310752,
0.884748080310752,
0.884748080310752,
0.884748080310752,
0.839632014230907,
0.839632014230907,
0.839632014230907,
0.839632014230907,
0.839632014230907,
0.839632014230907,
0.839632014230907,
0.839632014230907,
0.839632014230907,
0.839632014230907,
0.839632014230907,
0.839632014230907,
1.1229204406206,
1.1229204406206,
1.1229204406206,
1.1229204406206,
1.1229204406206,
1.1229204406206,
1.1229204406206,
1.1229204406206,
1.1229204406206,
1.1229204406206,
1.1229204406206,
1.1229204406206,
0.940763778922923,
0.940763778922923,
0.940763778922923,
0.940763778922923,
0.940763778922923,
0.940763778922923,
0.940763778922923,
0.940763778922923,
0.940763778922923,
0.940763778922923,
0.940763778922923,
0.940763778922923,
0.74844803241941,
0.74844803241941,
0.74844803241941,
0.74844803241941,
0.74844803241941,
0.74844803241941,
0.74844803241941,
0.74844803241941,
0.74844803241941,
0.74844803241941,
0.74844803241941,
0.74844803241941,
0.72039682140522,
0.72039682140522,
0.72039682140522,
0.72039682140522,
0.72039682140522,
0.72039682140522,
0.72039682140522,
0.72039682140522,
0.72039682140522,
0.72039682140522,
0.72039682140522,
0.72039682140522,
0.783237079191968,
0.783237079191968,
0.783237079191968,
0.783237079191968,
0.783237079191968,
0.783237079191968,
0.783237079191968,
0.783237079191968,
0.783237079191968,
0.783237079191968,
0.783237079191968,
0.783237079191968,
0.731030391679879,
0.731030391679879,
0.731030391679879,
0.731030391679879,
0.731030391679879,
0.731030391679879,
0.731030391679879,
0.731030391679879,
0.731030391679879,
0.731030391679879,
0.731030391679879,
0.731030391679879,
0.9502595494971,
0.9502595494971,
0.9502595494971,
0.9502595494971,
0.9502595494971,
0.9502595494971,
0.9502595494971,
0.9502595494971,
0.9502595494971,
0.9502595494971,
0.9502595494971,
0.9502595494971,
0.717754884271775,
0.717754884271775,
0.717754884271775,
0.717754884271775,
0.717754884271775,
0.717754884271775,
0.717754884271775,
0.717754884271775,
0.717754884271775,
0.717754884271775,
0.717754884271775,
0.717754884271775,
0.748972997706123,
0.748972997706123,
0.748972997706123,
0.748972997706123,
0.748972997706123,
0.748972997706123,
0.748972997706123,
0.748972997706123,
0.748972997706123,
0.748972997706123,
0.748972997706123,
0.748972997706123,
0.731569637966974,
0.731569637966974,
0.731569637966974,
0.731569637966974,
0.731569637966974,
0.731569637966974,
0.731569637966974,
0.731569637966974,
0.731569637966974,
0.731569637966974,
0.731569637966974,
0.731569637966974,
0.82600544303205,
0.82600544303205,
0.82600544303205,
0.82600544303205,
0.82600544303205,
0.82600544303205,
0.82600544303205,
0.82600544303205,
0.82600544303205,
0.82600544303205,
0.82600544303205,
0.82600544303205,
0.860265230004144,
0.860265230004144,
0.860265230004144,
0.860265230004144,
0.860265230004144,
0.860265230004144,
0.860265230004144,
0.860265230004144,
0.860265230004144,
0.860265230004144,
0.860265230004144,
0.860265230004144,
0.862360483501427,
0.862360483501427,
0.862360483501427,
0.862360483501427,
0.862360483501427,
0.862360483501427,
0.862360483501427,
0.862360483501427,
0.862360483501427,
0.862360483501427,
0.862360483501427,
0.862360483501427,
0.81595650516483,
0.81595650516483,
0.81595650516483,
0.81595650516483,
0.81595650516483,
0.81595650516483,
0.81595650516483,
0.81595650516483,
0.81595650516483,
0.81595650516483,
0.81595650516483,
0.81595650516483,
0.821726883652184,
0.821726883652184,
0.821726883652184,
0.821726883652184,
0.821726883652184,
0.821726883652184,
0.821726883652184,
0.821726883652184,
0.821726883652184,
0.821726883652184,
0.821726883652184,
0.821726883652184,
1.00465118580511,
1.00465118580511,
1.00465118580511,
1.00465118580511,
1.00465118580511,
1.00465118580511,
1.00465118580511,
1.00465118580511,
1.00465118580511,
1.00465118580511,
1.00465118580511,
1.00465118580511,
1.01705694232554,
1.01705694232554,
1.01705694232554,
1.01705694232554,
1.01705694232554,
1.01705694232554,
1.01705694232554,
1.01705694232554,
1.01705694232554,
1.01705694232554,
1.01705694232554,
1.01705694232554,
1.1700312418641,
1.1700312418641,
1.1700312418641,
1.1700312418641,
1.1700312418641,
1.1700312418641,
1.1700312418641,
1.1700312418641,
1.1700312418641,
1.1700312418641,
1.1700312418641,
1.1700312418641,
1.03065226648825,
1.03065226648825,
1.03065226648825,
1.03065226648825,
1.03065226648825,
1.03065226648825,
1.03065226648825,
1.03065226648825,
1.03065226648825,
1.03065226648825,
1.03065226648825,
1.03065226648825,
0.984661287553648,
0.984661287553648,
0.984661287553648,
0.984661287553648,
0.984661287553648,
0.984661287553648,
0.984661287553648,
0.984661287553648,
0.984661287553648,
0.984661287553648,
0.984661287553648,
0.984661287553648,
1.10198473295472,
1.10198473295472,
1.10198473295472,
1.10198473295472,
1.10198473295472,
1.10198473295472,
1.10198473295472,
1.10198473295472,
1.10198473295472,
1.10198473295472,
1.10198473295472,
1.10198473295472,
1.19921300316797,
1.19921300316797,
1.19921300316797,
1.19921300316797,
1.19921300316797,
1.19921300316797,
1.19921300316797,
1.19921300316797,
1.19921300316797,
1.19921300316797,
1.19921300316797,
1.19921300316797,
0.976655549015761,
0.976655549015761,
0.976655549015761,
0.976655549015761,
0.976655549015761,
0.976655549015761,
0.976655549015761,
0.976655549015761,
0.976655549015761,
0.976655549015761,
0.976655549015761,
0.976655549015761,
1.00965253592154,
1.00965253592154,
1.00965253592154,
1.00965253592154,
1.00965253592154,
1.00965253592154,
1.00965253592154,
1.00965253592154,
1.00965253592154,
1.00965253592154,
1.00965253592154,
1.00965253592154,
0.906334059359132,
0.906334059359132,
0.906334059359132,
0.906334059359132,
0.906334059359132,
0.906334059359132,
0.906334059359132,
0.906334059359132,
0.906334059359132,
0.906334059359132,
0.906334059359132,
0.906334059359132,
1.14708067935416,
1.14708067935416,
1.14708067935416,
1.14708067935416,
1.14708067935416,
1.14708067935416,
1.14708067935416,
1.14708067935416,
1.14708067935416,
1.14708067935416,
1.14708067935416,
1.14708067935416,
0.955497703496012,
0.955497703496012,
0.955497703496012,
0.955497703496012,
0.955497703496012,
0.955497703496012,
0.955497703496012,
0.955497703496012,
0.955497703496012,
0.955497703496012,
0.955497703496012,
0.955497703496012,
0.804850441796246,
0.804850441796246,
0.804850441796246,
0.804850441796246,
0.804850441796246,
0.804850441796246,
0.804850441796246,
0.804850441796246,
0.804850441796246,
0.804850441796246,
0.804850441796246,
0.804850441796246,
0.887492658652853,
0.887492658652853,
0.887492658652853,
0.887492658652853,
0.887492658652853,
0.887492658652853,
0.887492658652853,
0.887492658652853,
0.887492658652853,
0.887492658652853,
0.887492658652853,
0.887492658652853,
0.946400263687437,
0.946400263687437,
0.946400263687437,
0.946400263687437,
0.946400263687437,
0.946400263687437,
0.946400263687437,
0.946400263687437,
0.946400263687437,
0.946400263687437,
0.946400263687437,
0.946400263687437,
0.921730362937116,
0.921730362937116,
0.921730362937116,
0.921730362937116,
0.921730362937116,
0.921730362937116,
0.921730362937116,
0.921730362937116,
0.921730362937116,
0.921730362937116,
0.921730362937116,
0.921730362937116,
1.03023550595632,
1.03023550595632,
1.03023550595632,
1.03023550595632,
1.03023550595632,
1.03023550595632,
1.03023550595632,
1.03023550595632,
1.03023550595632,
1.03023550595632,
1.03023550595632,
1.03023550595632,
0.921572456964006,
0.921572456964006,
0.921572456964006,
0.921572456964006,
0.921572456964006,
0.921572456964006,
0.921572456964006,
0.921572456964006,
0.921572456964006,
0.921572456964006,
0.921572456964006,
0.921572456964006,
0.889937018095707,
0.889937018095707,
0.889937018095707,
0.889937018095707,
0.889937018095707,
0.889937018095707,
0.889937018095707,
0.889937018095707,
0.889937018095707,
0.889937018095707,
0.889937018095707,
0.889937018095707,
0.916992726360386,
0.916992726360386,
0.916992726360386,
0.916992726360386,
0.916992726360386,
0.916992726360386,
0.916992726360386,
0.916992726360386,
0.916992726360386,
0.916992726360386,
0.916992726360386,
0.916992726360386,
0.916992726360386,
0.916992726360386,
0.916992726360386,
0.916992726360386,
0.916992726360386,
0.916992726360386,
0.916992726360386,
0.916992726360386,
0.916992726360386,
0.916992726360386,
0.916992726360386,
0.916992726360386,
0.916992726360386,
0.916992726360386,
0.916992726360386,
0.916992726360386,
0.916992726360386,
0.916992726360386,
0.916992726360386,
0.916992726360386,
0.916992726360386,
0.916992726360386,
0.916992726360386,
0.916992726360386,
0.916992726360386,
0.916992726360386
]);

//Create an Image Collection, each image.constant(value of list)
var Image_Multiplication = function(collection,valuelist){
  var list_size = valuelist.size();
  var sequence = ee.List.sequence(0,list_size.subtract(ee.Number(1)));

  var value_collection = ee.ImageCollection(sequence.map(function(i){
    return ee.Image.constant(list.get(i));
  }));

  var value_collection_list = value_collection.toList(value_collection.size());
  var collection_list = collection.toList(collection.size());

  return ee.ImageCollection(sequence.map(function(i){
    var image = ee.Image(collection_list.get(ee.Number(i)));
    var value_image = ee.Image(value_collection_list.get(ee.Number(i)));
    var multiplication_image = image.multiply(value_image);
    return ee.Image(multiplication_image);
  }));

};

var value_collection = Image_Multiplication(collection,list);

print(value_collection);

Map.addLayer(collection.first(),{},'Original Images',false);
Map.addLayer(value_collection.first(),{},'Multiplied Image',false);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to copy the image properties twice. The first time, you create a summed image from multiple images between `start` and `end`, thus you will have to pick one image to copy the properties from. for simplicity, I choose the first image:

```
var sum_month = ee.List.sequence(0, 39*12).map(function(n) { 
  var start = ee.Date('1981-01-01').advance(n, 'month'); // Starting date
  var end = start.advance(1, 'month'); // Step by each iteration

  // get collection filtered
  var imgColTemp = ee.ImageCollection("UCSB-CHG/CHIRPS/DAILY").filterDate(start, end);
  // get properties of the first image between the start and end
  var props = imgColTemp.first().toDictionary(imgColTemp.first().propertyNames());

  return imgColTemp.sum()
        .set('system:time_start', start.millis())
        .set(props); // set the properties
});
```

Then you create new image using `multiply`, and images loose their properties. Thus, copy them again at the end of your script:

```
    return ee.Image(multiplication_image)
          // copy image properties again
          .set(image.toDictionary(image.propertyNames()));
```

See [full code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/ca37f32db28c8d08e072b4f78f2e38c3)

Answer (score 1):

If you use `.copyProperties()` with default arguments, only ordinary (i.e. non-system) properties will be copied.

To copy all properties, including system properties, use `.copyProperties(image, image.propertyNames())`, or specify a list of properties that you want to copy.

See [link to the script](https://code.earthengine.google.com/06894811334bb77acb5fc7c986390693).